# Unresolved external symbol error (VS2013 Express)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, header-files

I've decided to get into C++, and I've been experimenting with SDL, classes, and header files.
I have a header file here:

```
class loaders
{
public:
loaders();
SDL_Surface * load_image(const char imageName[], SDL_PixelFormat *format);
};
```

And the CPP file here:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
//COMMENT
class loaders
{
public:
    loaders()
    {
        if (IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG)
        {
            std::cout << IMG_GetError();
        }
    }
    SDL_Surface * load_image(const char imageName[], SDL_PixelFormat *format)
    {
        SDL_Surface * returnSurface = nullptr;
        returnSurface = IMG_Load(imageName);
        if (returnSurface != NULL)
        {
            return SDL_ConvertSurface(returnSurface, format, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Image load failed." << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
            return NULL;
        }

    }
};
```

I know the the error means that the linker can't find something, but I can't for the life of me, figure out what it is. It's probably something small, so I thought another pair of eyes would help.

Comment: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall loaders::loaders(void)" (??0loaders@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Window::Window(void)" (??0Window@@QAE@XZ) C:\Users\Kevin\Source\Workspaces\SDL Checkers\SDL Checkers\SDL Checkers\main.obj SDL Checkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation file should use its own header file for the class declaration. You only need to define the member functions in loaders.cpp, like so:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "loaders.h"

loaders::loaders()
{
    if (IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG)
    {
        std::cout << IMG_GetError();
    }
}

SDL_Surface * loaders::load_image(const char imageName[], SDL_PixelFormat *format)
{
    SDL_Surface * returnSurface = nullptr;
    returnSurface = IMG_Load(imageName);
    if (returnSurface != NULL)
    {
        return SDL_ConvertSurface(returnSurface, format, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Image load failed." << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Include this implementation file in your project, and compile all of the sources in your project with the same flags (the default case). Then the compiler will use the same calling convention and name decoration for all references to your constructor, and the symbol will be found by the linker when it puts together all your object files into the executable.